# The caption of the table moved to the left

Tags: tables, captions, positioning

I am trying to add a table to my Latex document but the caption of the table shrunk in the left corner and does not extend to the whole width of the table.
This is my table:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % More fancy images
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize

\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.5cm}{}
  \resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\caption{The constraints on the content of the universe based on best fit to the $\Lambda$CDM model. The first column represents the results from adding different cosmological probes.}        
    \begin{tabular}{  l  c  c   c  c  p{5.cm} }
    \hline\hline
    Parameter & P+WP & P+WP+highL & P+WP+highL+L & P+WP+highL+L+BAO & Summary \\ \hline
    $\Omega_bh^2$ & 0.022032 & 0.022069 & 0.022199 & 0.022161 & Baryon    \\ 
    $\Omega_ch^2$& 0.12038 & 0.12025 & 0.11847 & 0.11889 & Cold dark matter \\
    $\Omega_mh^2$& 0.14305 & ... & ... & ... & Total matter \\ 
    $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ & 0.6817 & 0.6830 & 0.6939 & 0.6914 & Dark energy \\
    $\Sigma m_{\nu}$[eV]&0.002&...&0.000&...&neutrino\\
    $H_0$& 67.04&67.15&67.94&67.77&expansion rate \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}}
\end{adjustwidth}      
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What's the `adjustwidth` environment for? And why reducing the width to `.7\textwidth`?

Comment: @egreg I used it in order to fit the whole table in the width of the page, since it was extended more than the size of page.

Comment: That's the main reason for having it pushed on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the width of the table to `\textwidth` by choosing a `tabularx` environment. The only trick, so to say, is that whereas the body of the four middle columns ought to be specified to have column type `S` (from the `siunitx` package, so that the numbers are aligned on the decimal columns), the column headers should be specified to have (a modified form of the) column type `X` (provided by the `tabularx` package); this allows the long header lines to be split easily into two parts, while letting LaTeX figure out the column widths for you.

I also suggest you (a) use the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- to obtain well-spaced horizontal lines and (b) replace the `...` ellipses with `$\cdots$`.

With this setup, either specifying `\footnotesize` *or* using the `\resizebox` macro to make the table fit inside the text block turns out to be unnecessary. Put differently, it's feasible to typeset the table without a change in font size. Keeping font sizes constant across major elements of a document is usually considered desirable from a typographic point of view.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} % \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for "S" column type
\usepackage{tabularx} % for "tabularx" environment
\usepackage[justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash\centering}X}
\newcommand\MC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}  % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\sisetup{table-format=2.6, group-digits=false}

\caption{Constraints on the content of the universe based on best fit to the $\Lambda$CDM model. 
    The first column represents the results from adding different cosmological probes.}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{4}{S}  l @{}}
\toprule
Parameter & \MC{P$+$WP} & \MC{P$+$WP$+$highL} & \MC{P$+$WP$+$highL $+$L} & \MC{P$+$WP$+$highL $+$L$+$BAO} & Summary \\
\midrule
$\Omega_bh^2$ & 0.022032 & 0.022069 & 0.022199 & 0.022161 & Baryon\\ 
$\Omega_ch^2$& 0.12038 & 0.12025 & 0.11847 & 0.11889 & Cold dark matter \\
$\Omega_mh^2$& 0.14305 &  {$\cdots$}  &  {$\cdots$}  &  {$\cdots$}  & Total matter \\ 
$\Omega_{\Lambda}$ & 0.6817 & 0.6830 & 0.6939 & 0.6914 & Dark energy \\
$\Sigma m_{\nu}$[eV]&0.002& {$\cdots$} &0.000& {$\cdots$} &Neutrino\\
$H_0$& 67.04&67.15&67.94&67.77&Expansion rate \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: I understand from your comments that you may have a very old TeX distribution which doesn't feature the `siunitx` package and hence doesn't know about that package's `S` column type. I'm posting a second solution, which features the `dcolumn` package and its `d` column type to achieve decimal alignment of the numbers. Since the `dcolumn` package has been around for 20 years or so, I'm hopeful that your TeX distribution *does* include this package. (If it seems to you that the screenshot below looks *exactly* the same as the one above, that's indeed correct.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} % \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % decimal alignment of numbers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for "tabularx" environment
\usepackage[justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash\centering}X}
\newcommand\MC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}  % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]

\caption{Constraints on the content of the universe based on best fit to the $\Lambda$CDM model. 
    The first column represents the results from adding different cosmological probes.}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{4}{d{2.6}}  l @{}}
\toprule
Parameter 
& \MC{P$+$WP} 
& \MC{P$+$WP$+$highL} 
& \MC{P$+$WP$+$highL $+$L} 
& \MC{P$+$WP$+$highL $+$L$+$BAO} 
& Summary \\
\midrule
$\Omega_bh^2$ & 0.022032 & 0.022069 & 0.022199 & 0.022161 & Baryon\\ 
$\Omega_ch^2$& 0.12038 & 0.12025 & 0.11847 & 0.11889 & Cold dark matter \\
$\Omega_mh^2$& 0.14305 &  \MC{$\cdots$}  &  \MC{$\cdots$}  &  \MC{$\cdots$}  & Total matter \\ 
$\Omega_{\Lambda}$ & 0.6817 & 0.6830 & 0.6939 & 0.6914 & Dark energy \\
$\Sigma m_{\nu}$[eV]&0.002& \MC{$\cdots$} &0.000& \MC{$\cdots$} &Neutrino\\
$H_0$& 67.04&67.15&67.94&67.77&Expansion rate \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `caption` in your answer is centred, how could I change it to adjust from left and extend to the whole table

Comment: @dalek - Since the `caption` package is being loaded, it suffices to specify the options `justification=justified` and `singlelinecheck=false` when loading that package. I will update the example to reflect this requirement.

Comment: where should I use `justification=justified` option?

Comment: @Dalek - I've updated the code. The options `justification=justified` and `singlelinecheck=false` should be set when loading the `caption` package.

Comment: I have an old version of linux and probably it doesn't recognize `siunitx` package, is there any replacement?

Comment: I would use `${}+{}$` at least to give the sumation symbols a but of space.

Comment: @Manuel how should I replace it?

Comment: @Dalek With that comment I meant that rather than `Foo$+$Bar` (as he Mico uses in many cells) I would use `Foo${}+{}$Bar` (which will add a small space between the words and the plus sign, letting them breathe).

Comment: @Manuel - Given that space in the column headers is at a distinct premium, I chose deliberately not to let LaTeX insert any extra space by writing `{}+{}` (which, as I know you know as well, would insert `\medmuskip` at either side of the `+` symbol).

Comment: @dalek - I've posted an addendum that doesn't require the `siunitx` package. It uses the `dcolumn` package instead to achieve decimal marker alignment of the numbers. Since the `dcolumn` package has been around for, I'm guessing, roughly 20 years, I'm hopeful that the new solution will compile on your system.

Comment: @Mico I still get this error `! Undefined control sequence.
\@preamble ...l@width }\arraybackslash \Centering
\ignorespaces \@sharp \uns...
l.166 \end{tabularx}`

Comment: @Mico I don't understand what is wrong with my latex.

Comment: @Dalek - Are you using just my code, or some additional material as well? The reason I ask is that my code doesn't feature a `\Centering` instruction. (It does, though, feature a `\centering` instruction...)

Comment: @Mico yes. I think it has something to do with this line : `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash\centering}X}`

Comment: @Dalek - Note that `\Centering` and `\centering` are *not* the same. You mentioned earlier that you have "an old version of linux". Which TeX distribution, and which vintage, do you have? Any chance you could upgrade to the latest version of, say, TeXlive? For what it's worth, the `tabularx` package and the `array` package (which is loaded by `tabularx`) have been around for a very long time as well. If your TeX installation can't handle these packages, it's really time for an update. By the way, do you use LaTeX2e (which has been the standard since 1994) or the older LaTeX2.09?

Comment: @Mico I am using `TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0`.

Comment: @Mico hehehe.. It helped to use `\centering` instead of `\Centering`. Now it works. One little question: how could I break the text in the `Summary` column too?

Comment: Well, TeXLive2009 is somewhat geriatric by now, but not entirely fossilized. :-)  Glad that read that changing to `\centering` did the job. To allow line breaks in the right-hand-most column, change the column type from `l` to `X`.

Answer (score 3):

In general it's better to avoid rescaling a table; never rescale the caption.

Your main problem is due to the wide column headers; I don't think it's useful to have the table extending to the whole line width, so I'll present two solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,siunitx}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering\small

\caption{The constraints on the content of the universe based on best fit to the 
$\Lambda$CDM model. The first column represents the results from adding different 
cosmological probes.}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  l
  S[table-format=2.6]
  S[table-format=2.6]
  S[table-format=2.6]
  S[table-format=2.6]
  X
}
\toprule
Parameter
 & {$P+\var{WP}$}
 & {\splitcell{$P+\var{WP}\:+$\\$\var{highL}$}}
 & {\splitcell{$P+\var{WP}\:+$\\$\var{highL}+L$}}
 & {\splitcell{$P+\var{WP}\:+$\\$\var{highL}+L+\var{BAO}$}}
 & Summary
\\
\midrule
$\Omega_bh^2$              & 0.022032 & 0.022069 & 0.022199 & 0.022161 & Baryon \\ 
$\Omega_ch^2$              & 0.12038  & 0.12025  & 0.11847  & 0.11889  & Cold dark matter \\
$\Omega_mh^2$              & 0.14305  & {\dots}  & {\dots}  & {\dots}  & Total matter \\ 
$\Omega_{\Lambda}$         & 0.6817   & 0.6830   & 0.6939   & 0.6914   & Dark energy \\
$\Sigma m_{\nu}$ (\si{eV}) & 0.002    & {\dots}  & 0.000    & {\dots}  & neutrino \\
$H_0$                      & 67.04    & 67.15    & 67.94    & 67.77    & expansion rate $i$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{The constraints on the content of the universe based on best fit to the 
$\Lambda$CDM model. The first column represents the results from adding different 
cosmological probes.}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2.6]
  S[table-format=2.6]
  S[table-format=2.6]
  S[table-format=2.6]
  l
}
\toprule
Parameter
 & {$P+\var{WP}$}
 & {\splitcell{$P+\var{WP}\:+$\\$\var{highL}$}}
 & {\splitcell{$P+\var{WP}\:+$\\$\var{highL}+L$}}
 & {\splitcell{$P+\var{WP}\:+$\\$\var{highL}+L+\var{BAO}$}}
 & Summary
\\
\midrule
$\Omega_bh^2$              & 0.022032 & 0.022069 & 0.022199 & 0.022161 & Baryon \\ 
$\Omega_ch^2$              & 0.12038  & 0.12025  & 0.11847  & 0.11889  & Cold dark matter \\
$\Omega_mh^2$              & 0.14305  & {\dots}  & {\dots}  & {\dots}  & Total matter \\ 
$\Omega_{\Lambda}$         & 0.6817   & 0.6830   & 0.6939   & 0.6914   & Dark energy \\
$\Sigma m_{\nu}$ (\si{eV}) & 0.002    & {\dots}  & 0.000    & {\dots}  & neutrino \\
$H_0$                      & 67.04    & 67.15    & 67.94    & 67.77    & expansion rate $i$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, you don't need to rescale the table.

Comment: Thanks it looks promising but when I add it to my latex document, I get these errors `! LaTeX Error: \splitcell undefined.
l.49 \renewcommand{\splitcell}
[1]{%
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! LaTeX Error: \var undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.52 \renewcommand{\var}
[1]{\mathit{#1}}
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
(./aas_macros.sty) (./thesis.aux)
\openout1 = `thesis.aux'.
`

Comment: @Dalek - Did you copy the contents of the preamble of the code given above into the preamble of your document?

Comment: @Mico yes I did. But it seems it doesn't recognize `siunitx` package.

Comment: @Dalek - The `siunitx` package has been around for several years now and is distributed with both TeXlive and MiKTeX.  Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: In first `table`, it's not necessary to specify `\centering` if the width of the tabularx environment is set to `\textwidth`. Separately, the table will fit inside the text block even if `\small` is omitted.

Comment: @Mico The `\centering` suppresses indentation.

Comment: @egreg any substitution for `siunitx` package? My linux can not compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't require `\resizebox` nor `adjustwidth` nor loading the `changepage` package, using the `tabularx` environment, plus `booktabs,`makecell`(allowing for linebreaks in cells) and`siunitx` to improve the look of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{rc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.6,table-number-alignment=center}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{1cm}


\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize\captionsetup{format = hang, font=footnotesize, labelfont=sc}
\caption{The constraints on the content of the universe based on best fit to the $\Lambda$CDM model. The first column represents the results from adding different cosmological probes.}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l *{4}{S}X}
\toprule\midrule
Parameter & {P+WP} & {\thead{P+WP+highL}} & {\thead{P+WP+highL\\+L\mbox{\hskip1.9em}}} & {\thead{P+WP+highL\\+L+BAO}} & Summary \\
\midrule\addlinespace
$\Omega_bh^2$ & 0.022032 & 0.022069 & 0.022199 & 0.022161 & Baryon \\
$\Omega_ch^2$& 0.12038 & 0.12025 & 0.11847 & 0.11889 & Cold dark matter \\
$\Omega_mh^2$& 0.14305 & {...} & {...} & {...} & Total matter \\
$\Omega_{\Lambda}$ & 0.6817 & 0.6830 & 0.6939 & 0.6914 & Dark energy \\
$\Sigma m_{\nu}$[eV] & 0.002 & {...} & 0.000 & {...} &neutrino\\
$H_0$& {67.04} & {67.15} & {67.94} & {67.77} & expansion rate \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `...` strings should probably be replaced with typographically appropriate ellipses.

Comment: @Mico: I just copied the O.P. code, not knowing what he/she meant exactly with these dots.

Comment: @Bernard Plus I don't think $\Omega_b$ can be written the way you wrote it.

Comment: @ Dalek: Oops! Sorry, it's my editor that's configured to display greek letters such as `Ω` while saving them as \Omega, &c. Corrected.